# what is the real difference between the version field on the ip header and the type field in the ethernet header?

Tags: networking

the version field in the IP header contains the version of the IP protocol used (IPv4/IPv6).
the type field in the Ethernet header contains which layer 3 protocol to forward the De-encapsulated packet to (IPv4, IPv6).
Why is it so important that the IP header have a field called "Version", what is it used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networking protocols are designed in layered manner to reduce complexities and improve generalities. The IP layer is designed in such a way that each of system can have a suitable IP layer software to process the packets without worrying about how the packets are transferred. This way IP packets can be transported by ethernet layer or any other layer (e.g. FC or ATM) independent of the knowledge of layer below it. The IP processing software needs to know the version of IP and hence IP packets have that version.

The same layering concept applies to ethernet layer which can help in transporting not only IP packets but other type of packets (e.g. IPX) without knowing details about protocol that it is transporting. But the ethernet layer processing at each end should know what type of packets they are carrying, so that they can hand-over the packet to appropriate layer for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Because IP can be encapsulated in another (non-Ethernet) layer 2 protocol. The IP protocol does not mandate a specific lower layer protocol so it can not make assumption on information that is available at this layer (e.g. the upper layer protocol version number). So if the layer 2 protocol only specifies 'IP' as the next layer, you need the IP protocol version from the IP header to correctly process it.

Comment: So you say that the ethernet protocol needs that part of information that is inside the “Version” field from the IP header to fill the “Type” field in the ethernet protocol. If so, why the IP protocol doesn’t need a piece of information from the Transport layer header to fill the “next header” field?

Comment: No, the ethernet protocol (or any other layer 2 protocol) needs to specify what comes next, what next layer/data block is embedded. So, it could just say IP. Because at that point in time there's no thought that there could be different versions of IP. When the IP designer comes up with a new version, it can change the format and specifies in its own header the new version/layout.